# What does a て form i-adjective for sentence ending mean?

Tags: grammar, て-form, i-adjectives

Why is this i-adjective conjugated to the て form at the end of the sentence? Why not just leave it as 珍しい?

The only use I know for て form adjectives is so you can chain them together, but there is no other adjective here.

> 田舎育ちだからコンビニが**珍しくて**さ。
>
> Convince Stores are rare, because I grew up in the country.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write my opinion as a Japanese native speaker. My major is not linguistics.

I think ”田舎育ちだからコンビニが珍しい” is also correct expression. but leaving “”珍しい” feels more literary style.

I think your sentence come from daily conversations (sentence-ending particle “さ” is mostly using in conversation ). So the sentence “田舎育ちだからコンビニが珍しくてさ” has a context. Japanese language is called high context language. In this case, I think there are other events or conversations that cause your sentence. for example,

> person A「へぇ、なんでも売ってるんだね。」
>   person B「コンビニはどこもこんな感じじゃない？」
>   person A「田舎育ちだからコンビニが珍しくてさ。」

In this example, what person A want to say is that 田舎育ちだからコンビニが珍しくて驚いた. So the i-adjective is conjugated.

Comment: The context of this conversation was that the person moved to a big city for work, so your explanation makes sense to me. Thanks!